# JPA - отфильтровать список объектов по критерию их наличия в базе

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Если в кратце то мне нужно сделать такой запрос при помощи jpql чтобы, передавая в него список сущностей, мне возвращалась та часть часть этого переданного списка, которая не была ранее сохранена в базу(т.е. те сущности из списка что в базе отсутствуют).
Я довольно долго сидел пытаясь создать его самостоятельно, но пока что безуспешно.

Comment: *чтобы остались только те, что отсутствуют в базе* WHERE NOT EXISTS либо LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL. *список может состоять из сотен/тысяч элементов, в базе как минимум будет столько же* Тогда лучше слить их сначала во временную таблицу. И проиндексировать.

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: @Akina, а разве есть техническая возможность получить результат который будет состоять только из того что я в jpql запрос параметром передал? Просто я понимаю как использовать WHERE NOT EXISTS если нужно получить записи из базы которых нет в переданном списке, но не очень понимаю как получить элементы списка коих нет в базе.

Comment: Начните с отдельного запроса для каждого элемента. Потом подумайте как сделать запросами по 10 элементов, потом по 100(хотя это точно так же как для 10:) А потом одновременно 10 запросов по 10/100 элементов.

Comment: @Sergey попробую)

Comment: *а разве есть техническая возможность получить результат который будет состоять только из того что я в jpql запрос параметром передал?* Конечно. Простейший пример: `SELECT ? AS output;`

Comment: @Akina jpql сильно упрощён и против обычного sql. куда уж там до фокусов с параметрами.

Comment: @Sergey Вопрос помечен тегом PostgreSQL. И это не я такой тег установил...

Comment: @Akina а вопрос про jpa. хотя... совершенно выпало из головы, что jpa может выполнять и нативные запросы, в том числе такой SELECT ?

Comment: По какому критерию определяется что данная сущность была сохранена в БД? Спрашиваю потому, что есть разные варианты. Можно проверить поле первичного ключа, а можно проверять все поля сущности. Как вы для конкретной сущности хотите проверять, что она уже сохранена, особенно учитывая, что у несохраненных сущностей обычно нет значения в поле первичного ключа? В этом контексте также можнет быть важно, как именно сущность получает свой первичный ключ. Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.